# Meaning of "to scratch"

Tags: meaning, verbs

Can the verb *to scratch* mean "start from the beginning"?

Can I say "I scratched" to say "I started from the beginning"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, to scratch cannot mean “start from the beginning”. This is expressed by “to start from scratch”:

> **from scratch:** from the very beginning, esp. without utilizing or relying on any previous work for assistance: *he built his own computer company from scratch*.

---

Also, beware! The verb *scratch* can also mean *to cancel or abandon*, so saying “I scratched the project” would not mean you've started it from nothing, but that you cancelled it.